# Post permalinks go to the home page

Tags: permalinks, redirect

The site is hosted with 1&1 and yesterday they added a ssl cert to the site.

The site automatically updated to 4.7 overnight.

The main pages are all working, and permalinks to pages are also working fine,
which I thing suggest the htaccess is correct

```
# AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
# AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What is very strange is that the Pages permalinks work fine it's only the Posts ones which are wrong.

With Permalinks turned on for posts they all redirect back to the homepage.

The only rewrite filter I can find is 
   add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'wc_fix_rewrite_rules' );
for WooCommerce.

I have the redirect plugin as well, but that has always worked fine for me and disabling it made no difference.

Can anyone suggest anything else to look at. Other than turning off each plugin in turn (the site has loads active).
..

In the end
Could not solve the problem,  so restored back prior to the updates.

Comment: You could always disable ALL plugins.  If no change then you've resolved that trouble shooting direction.  If it does fix the problem though, you know it's a plugin.  That's how I would start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repairing htaccess in WordPress all you need is to delete this file and then enter wp-admin -> settings > permalinks > save.

But i'm still not sure i understand the problem you are having..
If i understand, when friendly urls are on you get blank posts but not pages and when you are using the default id urls everything is fine.

Is that it?

Comment: I have already tried the first option without success.   Setting Permalinks to %POST_NAME% means all post links go back to the home page,  but Wordpress Pages go to the correct page.